# Get JSON stringify value

Tags: javascript, json, loops, stringify

I have JSON stringify data like this :

```
[{"availability_id":"109465","date":"2017-02-21","price":"430000"},{"availability_id":"109466","date":"2017-02-22","price":"430000"},{"availability_id":"109467","date":"2017-02-23","price":"430000"}]
```

I want to get only **price** value of that data. I have tried this way but it doesn't work.

```
var stringify = JSON.stringify(values);

for(var i = 0; i < stringify.length; i++)
{
    alert(stringify[i]['price']);
}
```

How could I to do that ?

Comment: I `stringify` the name of your variable ? Or are you refering to the `JSON.stringify` methode ?
And then, is this variable the json string you posted ?

Comment: @Sylvain `var stringify = JSON.stringify(values);` I got from that.

Comment: wat error u getting its working fine for me in console of chrome

Comment: @Asad I got undefined in alert box.

Comment: refer to my naswer @Antonio

Comment: @Asad ok, I got it. thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This code will only fetch the price details.

```
var obj = '[{"availability_id":"109465","date":"2017-02-21","price":"430000"},{"availability_id":"109466","date":"2017-02-22","price":"430000"},{"availability_id":"109467","date":"2017-02-23","price":"430000"}]';
var stringify = JSON.parse(obj);
for (var i = 0; i < stringify.length; i++) {
    console.log(stringify[i]['price']);
}
```

Comment: it's necessary to note that the variables in this code snippet are named badly (the op fault). I would change it as: `obj` -> `jsonString` (or `dataString`),  `stringify` -> `jsonObj` (or `parsedData`, or simply `data`)

Answer (score 10):

**Observation :**

If you want to parse the `array of objects` to get the property `value` you have to convert in into `JSON object` first.

**DEMO**

```js
var jsonStringify = '[{"availability_id":"109465","date":"2017-02-21","price":"430000"},{"availability_id":"109466","date":"2017-02-22","price":"430000"},{"availability_id":"109467","date":"2017-02-23","price":"430000"}]';

var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonStringify);

for(var i = 0; i < jsonObj.length; i++)
{
    alert(jsonObj[i]['price']);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you will  geting a stringified object like this

```
var obj='[{"availability_id":"109465","date":"2017-02-21","price":"430000"},
{"availability_id":"109466","date":"2017-02-22","price":"430000"},
{"availability_id":"109467","date":"2017-02-23","price":"430000"}]';
```

parse your obj using JSON.parse(object) 
then apply this loop ad let me know it get any error 
lie this

```
var parseObject = JSON.parse(object);
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `stringify` before selecting the data you should use your loop directly on the `values` array.

For example :

```
var priceArray = array();
values.forEach (data) {
    alert(data['price'];
    priceArray.push(data['price']);
}

stringify = JSON.stringify(values);
stringifiedPriceArray = JsON.stringify(priceArray);
```

Once stringified, you can't reach the data in your array